# change background of certain websites black?

Tags: 11.10, google, desktop-background

Example would be inverting the background color of sites like google, reddit, and changing the text color to white or blue.

Also, gconf-editor doesn't seem to work when trying to rearrange the buttons on my windows, Did something change with 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this FireFox addon for changing the style of websites:

http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/